# How to add properties to a object in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to add a property 'time' to my object, but there is something wrong

I have tried some way, just like Vue.set, `this.$set`, or add properties in a directly way `(object.newProperty = 'XXX')`, but it didn't work

```
this.allOrderList.forEach((item) => {
     this.$set(item, 'time', this.getTime())
     Vue.set(item, 'time', this.getTime())
     item.time = this.getTime()
})

getTime () {
     return Math.round(Math.random()*(60 - 30)+30)
}
```

Can someone help me to resolve it ? thank you

Comment: Hi Jeremy. What is making you think that the code isn't working? Either of the first two options look okay, and the third option might be okay in some circumstances.

Comment: Hey Stephen, i also think it is ok, but it just can't work, here is the warning code i got :  `Property or method "time" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. `

Comment: If you are doing something in your template where you require time to have a value (e.g. `v-if="time.length > 0"` then you will get that error.

Comment: yeah, i use it like this `<p class="arrive_time">{{item.time}} minutes arrive</p>` ,but why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing your full code it is hard to say what the issue is as `Vue.set(item, 'time', this.getTime())` is the correct syntax for adding properties.

Here is a fiddle with your code adding the property time to a list of items https://jsfiddle.net/1vnfjh62/. Maybe it will help you see the problem in your code.

EDIT 1:

From the code in your comment I think the issue is that you are setting `allOrderList` to be the array object from your server. You should just add items from the server to your vue.js array. So you'd initialise your Vue.js like so:

```
data: {
    allOrderList: []
}
```

Then append items to your array from the server:

```
    this.axios.get('/order/refresh').then((res) => {         
      res.data.data.forEach((item) => { 
        item.created_at = timestampToTime(item.created_at) 
        item.time = this.getTime()
        this.allOrderList.push(item)
      })
    })
```

You don't need to use `Vue.set(...)` here as it is not yet a reactive object.

Comment: wow, man , it works! here is my full code: `this.axios.get('/order/refresh').then((res) => {
                this.allOrderList = res.data.data
                this.allOrderList.forEach((item) => {
                    item.created_at = timestampToTime(item.created_at)
                    this.$set(item, 'time', this.getTime())
                })`  the value of 'allOrderList' is got from the data of axios, maybe it is wrong here ?